# Black shape over Flowplayer video on iPhone?

Tags: html, responsive-design, flowplayer

Has anyone figured out how to get rid of these black areas that cover the new Flowplayer when viewed on an Iphone? These F-bags at Flowplayer have the balls to say it works everywhere, yet in their own demo you can see the problem.
You can see the bg image shows a little sliver on the bottom, but 98% of the screen is covered in black. 
I see some solutions online so far but nothing works.

View on Iphone and you'll see the issue: http://flowplayer.org/demos/

Thank you in advance for an answers, ideas or directions.

Comment: same issue here! and: the playlist feature isn't working. to be exact: the whole JS API does not work on an iphone. if i call "var api = flowplayer()" ... api is 'undefined'. on ipad it works like a charme... did you find a solution already? my customer just paid 70 euros for this player and i dont want to tell him to spend another 70 for another one ;)